# In Excel, how do I get a list of cells to display based on an if function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list of quantities with a description column. It's counting doors based on size. I'd like to output a list (preferably separated by commas) of the description numbers with applicable numbers. Here's an example of what I have:

```
 A | B   | C   | D   | E   | F   |

Apt| 2'0 | 2'6 | 3'0 | 4'0 | 5'0 |

44 | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   | 1   |

47 | 0   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 2   |

48 | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |

50 | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   |
```

I'm trying to get it to generate a list of the apartment numbers grouped by the size, so it would read like:

```
2'0 | 50 (1)

2'6 | 44 (1), 47 (1), 48 (1)

3'0 | 48 (1)

4'0 | 44 (1), 48 (1), 50 (1)

5'0 | 44 (1), 47 (2), 48 (1), 50 (1)
```

I tried doing an IF function as follows:

```
=IF(B2:B5>0,A3:A5,)
```

but it only returns the first value it finds. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using OFFSET() as in
`=IF(B2:B5>0;A2:A5 &", "& OFFSET(A2:A5;0;1);)`

Comment: I currently can't think up a way to create a list though. You will probably need VBA (a macro).

Answer (score 0):

We can get tricksy with this. I pasted your data into the range `A1:F5`. Below that, I created a table whose end result looks like this CSV:

```
Door,Apts,44,47,48,50
2'0,50 (1),,,,50 (1), 
2'6,44 (1), 47 (1), 48 (1),44 (1), ,47 (1), ,48 (1), ,
3'0,48 (1),,,48 (1), ,
4'0,44 (1), 48 (1), 50 (1),44 (1), ,,48 (1), ,50 (1), 
5'0,44 (1), 47 (2), 48 (1), 50 (1),44 (1), ,47 (2), ,48 (1), ,50 (1),
```

For the `Door` field, I just copied your door sizes and pasted transposed
For the field names (44,47,48,50), I did the same with your apt numbers
For the `Apts` field, the formula for the first row is as follows:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(C11,D11,E11,F11),LEN(CONCATENATE(C11,D11,E11,F11))-2)
```

All it does is compile the data from the fields to the right
For those fields, the formula for the first cell is as follows:

```
=IF(INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$5,0,MATCH($A11,$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH(C$10,$A$2:$A$5,0))>0,C$10 & " (" &INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$5,0,MATCH($A11,$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH(C$10,$A$2:$A$5,0)) & "), ","")
```

It looks really long because a big chunk is repeated. That chunk is:

```
INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$5,0,MATCH($A11,$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH(C$10,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

All it does is pull the value from the table in `A1:F5` for this particular door size and apt
Replacing that chunk with just `INDEX(...)` we get:

```
=IF(INDEX(...)>0,C$10 & " (" &INDEX(...) & "), ","")
```

So it looks up the value and returns blank if it's zero or something like `50 (1),` if it's not
The `Apts` field then groups them all together and removes the trailing comma + space

---

Obviously, this may or may not work for you depending on the size of your dataset. However, I assume the number of apts and doors aren't changing any time soon so it should be worth it for one go-around.